# can't check node version by installing via node version manager

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-14.04, apt, nvm

I am trying to install nodejs via NVM. I use the tutorial here (https://github.com/creationix/nvm). After running `nvm install v0.10.25`, I try to check current node version by running `node -v`, but it says `The program 'nodejs' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
apt-get install nodejs`. What's wrong with this?

Comment: Have you run `nvm use 0.10.25`?

Comment: Yes.
root@lio:~# nvm use 0.10.25
Now using node v0.10.25 (npm v1.3.24)
root@lio:~# node -v
The program 'nodejs' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
apt-get install nodejs

Comment: try `which node` , and what's your os (windows or linux) ? I met same problem with windows-nvm